# How to hide default "N/A" option for checkboxes?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have a "gender" (checkbox) option that I want to show on the user profile page (but not on the registration page).
The options are "Male" (default) and "Female". Since I don't make the field required it is showing the "N/A" option. Drupal does this [by design](http://drupal.org/node/1080726).

If I make the field required the "N/A" option will go away but then it will automatically show on the registration page which I don't want.

I was trying to hide it with CSS but I cannot see a way to just hide that checkbox and "N/A" text:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-gender-und">
<input id="edit-field-gender-und-none" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="_none" name="field_gender[und]">
<label class="option" for="edit-field-gender-und-none">N/A </label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-gender-und">
<input id="edit-field-gender-und-0" class="form-radio" type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" name="field_gender[und]">
<label class="option" for="edit-field-gender-und-0">Male </label>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-gender-und">
<input id="edit-field-gender-und-1" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="1" name="field_gender[und]">
<label class="option" for="edit-field-gender-und-1">Female </label>
</div>
```

Help! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery to accomplish this

```
$("#edit-field-gender-und-none").remove();
```

Comment: I haven't used jQuery yet. Isn't it the same as adding this CSS: .edit-field-gender-und-none {
    display: none;
} this doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Here is a great write up on using JS in Drupal 7.
http://drupal.org/node/756722  Specifically here is how you would implement    `(function ($) {
  $("#edit-field-gender-und-none").remove();
}(jQuery));`

Comment: Is there any REAL way to do this? Doing it after the fact with css or javascript means that there is a small chance for it to be visible as the javascript is loading and executing.

Comment: Please don't do this. See kenorb's suggestion below.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better way to acheive this would be to write a simple [form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) hook and `unset()` the option you don want from your field.

```
function YOURMOD_form_YOURFORM_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  unset($form['YOURFIELD']['und']['#options']['_none']);
}
```

in the example above, the field is a taxonomy reference field on an entity edit form, so there is the extra `['und']` - it doesnt have to be there under all ocasions. You may want to `dpm($form)` first, to see the structure of the form.

Comment: You really shouldn't hard code 'und' in there if you can avoid it. And if you must do it, use the constant LANGUAGE_NONE instead.

Comment: Works, but then I get the `Notice: Use of undefined constant _none - assumed '_none' in MYMODULE_form_NODE_ID_form_alter()`

Comment: This doesn't work in D7 for fields api.

Answer (score 3):

Another quick solution is to have Drupal add a form-disabled class to the N/A form-item by adding the following function to your template.php file.

```
function <theme_name>_form_element($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  // Disable radio button N/A
  if ($element['#type'] == 'radio' && $element['#return_value'] === '_none') {
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
  }
  return theme_form_element($variables);
}
```

Then you can use CSS to do

```
.form-radios .form-disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 try the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
 */
function MODULENAME_element_info_alter(&$type) {
  $type['radios']['#process'][] = '_remove_radio_na';
  $type['select']['#process'][] = '_remove_radio_na';
}

/**
 * Removes the '_none' option from a form element.
 */
function _remove_radio_na($element) {
  unset($element['#options']['_none']);
  unset($element['_none']);
  return $element;
}
```

Make sure you clear caches, otherwise it won't work.

This is a better way than hiding results with CSS or JS/jQuery as empty values are removed before the output.

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

`jQuery("#edit-field-gender-und-none")[0].children[0].remove();`

Answer (score -1):

One of the interesting Features of Drupal 7 is the Field API. Prior to Drupal 6, to make a custom field the Core Profile Module and Content Profile Modules are used. Now in Drupal 7 we can make any custom field to appear in User Registration Form. When Adding Custom Fields Such as Gender usually we use Radio Button Input. However there is a small Problem with the core module as it displays the third option N/A in the input. To Remove the N/A option the field needs to be set as mandatory. To Remove this option there is another way. Go to modules/field/modules/options/options.module and comment the the code $properties['empty_option'] = ‘option_none’ as shown below under buttons.

```
case ‘buttons’:
$properties = array(
‘filter_xss’ => TRUE,
);
// Add a ‘none’ option for non-required radio buttons.
if (!$required && !$multiple) {
//$properties['empty_option'] = ‘option_none’; 
}
break;

case ‘onoff’:
$properties = array(
‘filter_xss’ => TRUE,
);
break;
}
```

However the proper way to achieve it would be to override this function in custom module. But for a quick fix we can also follow this method. [blog]: http://yamafm.wordpress.com/ "click here for updates"